# Proving that a matrix is primitive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

What is the easiest way to show that $B$ is primitive if there exists $q \in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $B_{qj}>0$ and $B_{iq}>0$ for all $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$?

Comment: You are asking for the easiest way to prove something… Do you know *any* way to prove it? How are we to know if our proof is easier that yours if you do not tell us what yours is?

Comment: You probably want to suppose that $B$ has non-negative entries…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $B$ is nonnegative. Therefore $B^k$ has the same sign pattern as $\operatorname{sign}(B)^k$ for all positive integers $k$. Thus you may assume that all positive entries of $B$ are equal to $0$ or $1$. Now let $C$ be the matrix whose elements are equal to $1$ on the $q$-th row and the $q$-th column, and zero elsewhere. Then $B^2\ge C^2$. However, note that all entries of $C^2$ are equal to $1$, except that the $q$-th diagonal entry of $C^2$ is $n$. Hence $B^2\ge C^2>0$ and $B$ is primitive.

Alternatively, view $B$ as a non-negatively weighted adjacency matrix. Then node $q$ is joined to every node (including $q$ itself) and every node is joined to $q$. Hence every node can reach itself via a path of length $2$. This means $B^2$ is positive and $B$ is primitive.

Comment: Why are the entries of $B^2$ equal to $1$?!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Uhh, I have implicitly converted all positive entries of $B$ into $1$. Fixed now.

Comment: @user1551 Why/how does a non-negatively weighted adjacency matrix tell us that node q is joined to every node?

Comment: @user1551 Couldn't some entries be zero, in which case some nodes would not be connected to others?

Comment: @mathbioguy No. As $B_{qj}>0$ for all $j$, node $q$ is joined to every node $j$ by a directed arc. Similarly, as $B_{iq}>0$ for all $i$, each node $i$ is joined to node $q$ by a directed arc. Consequently, each node $i$ reaches itself via the path $i\rightarrow q\rightarrow i$ of length $2$.